# Is kafka streams good solution to group messages from topic and send further

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm working on a Kafka Streams application and I want to batch data from topic grouped by key and send the grouped data further. I'm not entirely sure if Kafka Streams is a good solution to do that operations.

I've written the following code to illustrate this case:

```
KTable<Windowed<Long>, MessageDataAggregated> reduce = input
    .mapValues((ValueMapper<MessageData, MessageDataAggregated>) MessageDataAggregated::new)
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(longSerde, messageDataAggregatedSerde))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(1L)))
    .reduce(MessageDataAggregated::reduce)
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofMinutes(1L), Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()));

reduce.toStream().to("message-stream")
```

Are there any potential issues I should consider? Or is there any other better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The potential issue for aggregation is - does MessageDataAggregated contain a list which gets appended to. By default a kafka message size is 1MB, so if you are appending to a list you run the risk of crossing that threshold.

When using the reduce function keep in mind it won't propagate your tombstones, so if you have need of deletion downstream you'll have to handle it. A simple solution would be to have a flag in you aggregate and after aggregation map it down.